# Internal speaker (Audio) is not muting anymore in Ubuntu 21.10 after upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 21.10

After upgrading to 21.10, the internal speakers aren't listed as separate device anymore (now: speaker+).

- Therefore cannot be muted individually, or automatically, when notebook is on dock & line-out is connected. Still mutes, when
- plugging in direct on notebooks 3.5mm headphones out (changes from speaker+ -> headphones in alsamixer).

lspci shows:
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

Alsamixer shows:

- Device: HDA Intel PCH Chip:
- Conexant CX20724

could not figure out, any working set in: hdajackretask

Any help appreciated

Comment: Neither 21.04 nor 21.10 are LTS.

Comment: True. This was a c&p issue.
Thx for the hint.
However, despite this comments are technically correct, they doesn't answer the real question, nor get even close to the topic.